# Python BeautifulSoup find_all 'ascii' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup for extraction of the links to different electoral subregions outcomes from [Krasnodar krai elections](http://www.krasnodar.vybory.izbirkom.ru/region/region/krasnodar?action=show&root=1&tvd=2232000821586&vrn=2232000821581&region=23&global=&sub_region=23&prver=2&pronetvd=1&vibid=2232000821586&type=381). The links from html could be detected using word 'option'. html snippet:

```
<form name="go_reg">Нижестоящие избирательные комиссии:  <select name="gs"><option val="">---</option>
<option value="http://www.krasnodar.vybory.izbirkom.ru/region/krasnodar?action=show&amp;root=123400103&amp;tvd=2232000821616&amp;vrn=2232000821581&amp;prver=2&amp;pronetvd=1&amp;region=23&amp;sub_region=23&amp;type=381&amp;vibid=2232000821616">1 Абинская</option>
<option value="http://www.krasnodar.vybory.izbirkom.ru/region/krasnodar?action=show&amp;root=123402603&amp;tvd=2232000821591&amp;vrn=2232000821581&amp;prver=2&amp;pronetvd=1&amp;region=23&amp;sub_region=23&amp;type=381&amp;vibid=2232000821591">2 Анапская</option>
```

Here is my code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
contenturl = "http://www.krasnodar.vybory.izbirkom.ru/region/region/krasnodar?action=show&root=1&tvd=2232000821586&vrn=2232000821581&region=23&global=&sub_region=23&prver=2&pronetvd=1&vibid=2232000821586&type=381"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(contenturl).read(), 'html.parser', from_encoding = 'windows-1252')
soup.find_all('option')
```

However, I got following error:

```
 UnicodeDecodeError:'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 283: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried to find the answer, and one of suggestions was to set the encoding manually using "from_encoding" option, but this did not resolve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your beautiful soup open, you can avoid the error.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "http://www.krasnodar.vybory.izbirkom.ru/region/region/krasnodar?action=show&root=1&tvd=2232000821586&vrn=2232000821581&region=23&global=&sub_region=23&prver=2&pronetvd=1&vibid=2232000821586&type=381" #/air-jordan-1-retro-high-og-unc-white-dk-powder-blue-012304"
page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
for myValue in soup.find_all('option'):
    try:
        print(myValue.get_text() + " : " + myValue.get("value"))
    except:
        print("")
```

It generates

```
1 Àáèíñêàÿ : http://www.krasnodar.vybory.izbirkom.ru/region/krasnodar?action=show&root=123400103&tvd=2232000821616&vrn=2232000821581&prver=2&pronetvd=1&region=23&sub_region=23&type=381&vibid=2232000821616
2 Àíàïñêàÿ : http://www.krasnodar.vybory.izbirkom.ru/region/krasnodar?action=show&root=123402603&tvd=2232000821591&vrn=2232000821581&prver=2&pronetvd=1&region=23&sub_region=23&type=381&vibid=2232000821591
3 Àïøåðîíñêàÿ : http://www.krasnodar.vybory.izbirkom.ru/region/krasnodar?action=show&root=123400203&tvd=2232000821617&vrn=2232000821581&prver=2&pronetvd=1&region=23&sub_region=23&type=381&vibid=2232000821617
....etc
```